# AWS w/nginx redirect to docker containers; getting bad gateway 502

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, docker, nginx

The setup is a RHEL AWS instance.  On this instance, nginx is installed and working.  That means if I go to http://[root] I get the html in the nginx folder like I'm supposed to.  If I go to http://[root]/[sub1] I also get the other html in the nginx folder like I'm supposed to.

Now, http://[root]/[sub2] is a django server in a docker container.  When runserver, the django app is listening on http://127.0.0.1:8000.  My docker container translates :38000->:8000 via docker-compose.yml.
My nginx.conf file looks like this:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;

    location / {}

    location /test {
        index text.html;
        alias /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    location /mod {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:38000;
    }
}
```

While the root and /test (sub1) locations work, whenever I go to /mod (sub2), I get a 502 Bad Gateway.

My docker-compose.yml (version 2) contains `ports: 38000:8000`.  When I create the container, I use `docker-compose run --name mod mod`.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Does it work if you change your django app to listen on 0.0.0.0:8000?

Comment: `docker-compose run` also doesn't publish `ports:`; it's intended to run a one-off container while the main container is running (for example, it's one path to run database migrations).  Does `docker-compose up -d mod` work better?

Comment: @jordanm That did not work.
@DavidMaze ```docker-compose up -d mod``` did not work.  I also tried ```docker-compose run --service-ports```.  The ```docker ps``` does show 38000->8000 doing it either way.

Answer (score 0):

Two things needed to be fixed before working correctly.
First, the proxy_pass should have been 'http://localhost:38000',
and second, I had to run the Django app to listen to `0:8000` (i.e. `python manage.py runserver 0:8000`).

Using just `runserver` or `runserver 0.0.0.0:8000` didn't allow NGINX to send to the docker container.